# TypeScript/Angular try catch, any error in try block not going to catch block

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using Angular and TypeScript.
I have used try catch construct for error handling in case of API call.
If any error occurs in try block it is simply NOT going to catch block.
App terminates there only.

I have tried using `throw` as well. 
Here is a sample code snippet,

```
try {

  this.api.getAPI(Id).subscribe( // this.api is my api service and getAPI is present there
    (data: any) => {
      if (data == null) {
        throw 'Empty response';
      }
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(error);
    };

} catch(e) {
  console.log(e); 
}
```

in some cases 'data' from API returns 'null', 
but throw is not going to catch block
ALSO, tried without throw, it gives null error for 'data' ... in that case also not going to catch block.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `try/catch` won't catch anything in a callback passed to `subscribe` (or `then`, or `setTimeout` or anything smiilar) which runs on a different "tick" or "microtask". You have to catch errors in the task where they occurred.

I could suggest better alternatives if I understood what you were trying to do when the error occurred. If all you really want to do is to log it, you could of course do that right after the check for null.

You might consider mapping the observable prior to consuming it and issuing an error on the observable in case of a null, such as:

```
const checkedData = this.api.getAPI(Id).pipe(map(data => {
  if (data === null) return throwError("null data");
  return data;
});
```

Now you can subscribe with

```
checkedData.subscribe(
  data => /* do something with data */,
  console.error
);
```

Note: `throwError` is rxjs6. For rxjs5, it would be `return ErrorObservable("null data")` (I think).