# error from service not being caught in component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, service, error-handling

Once a user logs in, I retrieve their `userAccount`. In the case that it is not returned, I throw an error in the service. I then proceed to catch the error in a `component.ts` controller.

For some reason the `component.ts` does not catch the error being thrown. In console, I can see the errors, but for some reason my `component.ts` does not catch it in the `try/catch` block.

I've tested it multiple times to see where it failed and it seems that the error message doesn't reach the catch statement.

This is in my service:

```
/* On error: */
error => {

    if (error.status === 401) {

        Helpers.logGroupedErrorObjectsToDevConsole(
            'Login Service: getCustomerAccount()',
            [
                {
                    title: 'Session Timed Out:',
                    info:  true
                }
            ]
        );
    } else {
        Helpers.logGroupedErrorObjectsToDevConsole(
            'Login Service: getCustomerAccount()',
            [
                {
                    title: 'Cannot get customer account:',
                    info: true
                }
            ]
        );
    }

    throw new Error(error);
}
```

this is in my `component.ts`

```
try {
        setTimeout(() => {
           this._service.customer(this.url, this.route)
        }, 1000);
     } catch (e) { 
         this.showUnknownLoginFailureMessage  = true;
     }
```

What I expect is for the error to be handled in component.ts

Is it possible?
Am I doing the error handling properly or am I missing something?

I need some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A try/catch won't catch anything in a callback passed to subscribe (or
>   then, or **setTimeout** or anything smiilar) which runs on a different
>   "tick" or "microtask". You have to catch errors in the task where they
>   occurred.

There is a solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494803/7179294

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the exception by moving the `try... catch` statement inside of the `setTimeout` callback:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  try {
    this._service.customer(this.url, this.route);
  } catch (e) {
    this.showUnknownLoginFailureMessage  = true;
  }
}, 1000);
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjb2bd?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.