# How to break out of loop when error occurs

Tags: angular, loops

i am trying to break out of a for loop here on an error response and console the error message. Here is what i have tried

```
     var error = 0;
     var errorMsg;    
      for (let i = 0; i < this.fileArray.length; i++) {
          if ( this.fileArray[i] != undefined ) {
            if ( error == 0 ) {
              const fd = new FormData()
              fd.append('file', this.fileArray[i], this.fileArray[i].name)
              this.data.ImgUploader(fd).subscribe(
                res => {
                  if ( res['code'] != '00' ) { //error occurred. 1 is assigned to var error
                    error = 1
                    errorMsg = res['message']
                  } else {
                    error = 0
                  }
                }
              )
            } else {
              console.log(errorMsg)
              break;
            }
          }
        }
```

I am sending some image files via the `ImgUploader` function and recieving the response via the callback. I am trying to watch for errors via the error codes and assign `1` to the variable `error`. I expect variable `error == 1` now but the code still enters into the code block where `error == 0`. Please where could i be going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490176/typescript-angular-try-catch-any-error-in-try-block-not-going-to-catch-block

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to break out from the loop in the callback passed to `subscribe`. The callbacks are called after the loop is finished.

JavaScript code runs on a single thread. That's why in your code snippet first all the loop iterations will be executed. Since the `error` has value 0 all the time, `error == 0` will be true in all loop iterations. The callbacks of `subscribe` can be executed only after the loop is finished. At that time the value of `error` variable changes, but it does not make any difference because the loop is already finished.

If you want to know more what happens under the hood in the browser I recommend this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ